# How to reference a equation cross cell in jupyter markdown

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown

While using jupyter notebook, how can I reference equations cross cells? I found a way to referencing, but cannot auto update the displayed number.

`$a=b+c \tag{*}\label{eq1}$`

The referencing code `[1](#mjx-eqn-eq1)` displayed `1`. How can it display what's in `\tag{}` automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Since you create a markdown link and you name it `1`, this won't update. In general, Jupyter notebooks utilize [MathJax](https://docs.mathjax.org) (a subset of LaTeX) to render equations. The official [jupyter documentation](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebook.html?highlight=equation#markdown-cells) provides additional information and [examples](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/03bc4e9ed9871b3a9cb6dae537e467ac36f8fdaf/docs/source/examples/Notebook/Typesetting%20Equations.ipynb) it is said, that:

> Equation numbering and referencing will be available in a future version of the Jupyter notebook.

While this statement is quite old, it still seems still to be valid. As far as I can see, there are a couple of **options** to achieve numbering and referencing. Here is some examples:

- [MathJax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/tex.html#automatic-equation-numbering) provides numbering and linking. For me it did not at all work, maybe because of what the jupyter documentation says.
- Thus, I installed and activated [jupyter-contrib-nbextensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions) (jut as described in their readme).
- Now my equations are numbered (actually tagged) and the reference will be updated automatically. However, there seems an issue with auto numbering, since I always also have to define a number as tag. Here is an example:

```
    In equation \eqref{eq:sample}, we find the value of an
    interesting integral:
    
    \begin{equation}
      \int_0^\infty \frac{x^3}{e^x-1}\,dx = \frac{\pi^4}{15}
      \label{eq:sample} \tag{a}
    \end{equation}
```

Changing the tag will also update the reference. According documentation, using `\label` only should result in an automatically numbered equation (as in LaTeX), however that does not work for me. Maybe I have to install another extension to get it working.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've used  **jupyter-contrib-nbextensions** to achieve auto update tags in one cell already.  While editing a very long text with markdown in jupyter, it's always inconvenient to read, so I get used to split the whole text into different cells. In this case, I need to referencing equation in other cell. As the document said, there may not be a solution yet. Maybe I'll need to switch to another editing application. Oh, using one application for texting and another for coding, I'll be exhausted to switch all the time.

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be an issue. Did you try [jupyter book](https://jupyterbook.org/intro.html)? Its manual suggests that you may reference from/to multiple cells